# Jquery mobile get date in 24h format from ISO8601

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, date

I'm creating a website, that shows our week schedule and i have found some issues.

I retrieve all data from a JSON object like this below:

```
 [
    {"id":1, "start":"2011-10-29T13:15:00.000+10:00", "end":"2011-10-29T14:15:00.000+10:00", "title":"Meeting"}
 ]
```

The start date and the end date are in ISO8601 format. How can i cast this information to show it up in my website in a 24H format ? For this example it would be 13:15 - 15:00.

i let here the code

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$.getJSON("test.json", function(data){
                    var output = '';
                    for(key in data) {
                        output += convert(new Date(data[key].start)) + ' - ' + 
convert(new Date(data[key].end));
                    }
                });
                </script>
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function convert(date) {
                    var hour = date.getHours();
                    var minute = date.getMinutes();

                    if(hour < 10)
                        hour = "0" + hour
                    if(minute < 10)
                        minute = "0" + minute

                    return hour + ':' + minute
                }
            </script>
```

I hope it helps anyone else.

Answer (score 0):

Its not JQuery - but SugarJS has some excellent Date features : http://sugarjs.com/dates